# Adapt a Macro for Plone to display nothing if specific folder does not exist?

Tags: python, macros, plone

I have a macro for a Researcher Profile on Plone that I would like to adapt to display nothing if the desired folder does not exist. As it is now, if the "selected-publications" folder does not exist, it throws an error. Is it possible to make the macro display nothing if the "context/selected-publications/..." is empty or does not exist? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" i18n:domain="RDSLocal">
 <body>

    <div id="publications" metal:define-macro="publications" tal:omit-tag="">
      <!--publications-->
<a href="selected-publications"><h2>Publications</h2></a>
<ul style="list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">

<tal:block tal:repeat="publication context/selected-publications/getFolderContents">
  <li><tal:block tal:content="publication/Authors"/> (<tal:block tal:content="publication/publication_year"/>) <a tal:attributes="href publication/getURL" tal:content="publication/Title"/></li><br />
</tal:block>

</ul>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tal:define` and `tal:condition` to get and check the publications exist before you iterate through them with `tal:repeat`. Taking your code verbatim as a baseline:

```
<div id="publications" metal:define-macro="publications" tal:omit-tag="">
  <!--publications-->
  <a href="selected-publications"><h2>Publications</h2></a>
  <ul style="list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;"
      tal:define="publications nocall:context/selected-publications|nothing"
      tal:condition="publications">

    <tal:block tal:repeat="publication publications/getFolderContents">
      <li><tal:block tal:content="publication/Authors"/>
      (<tal:block tal:content="publication/publication_year"/>)
      <a tal:attributes="href publication/getURL"
      tal:content="publication/Title"/></li><br />
    </tal:block>

  </ul>
</div>
```

This is a common idiom in [Zope templates](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html). If you look in Plone's source code you'll find a treasure trove of examples of this technique that you can plunder.

Maybe you want to hide the `H2` if no publications exist? If so put the `tal:define` and `tal:condition` on the `div` instead.

Are you calling this from some other template? If not there's no need to define the snippet as a macro.

Comment: That works brilliantly, thank you so much! To answer your question, yes, this is being called from another template. We have a Researcher content type that has several display fields populated by macros (Job Title, Collaborators, Publications, etc.)

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust this so that the macro orders the display of the items in the folder by "publication_year"? As it is now, the order of the items in the folder is the order in which they are displayed.

Comment: Here's one way: assuming 'publication_year' is a catalog index, change the tal:repeat line to `<tal:block tal:repeat="publication python:publications.getFolderContents({'sort_on': 'publication_year'})">`